# Sizing Elastic Search Cluster / hot-warm architecture

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I am trying to implement a hot-warm architecture in order to configure a 6 month data retention (36 TB, 200 GB per day) policy in which data has to be deleted from an index 180 days after it has been indexed.

A hot index older than 40 days will enter the warm phase.

I would like to know How many nodes per phase should my cluster have? How many shard/ replicas should I create? What is the optimal average size of a shard for the best searching performance? What is the Capacity of RAM / Storage / CPU per node ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get what unit TO and GO means... can you explain it to me?

Comment: TB  and GB Sorry

Comment: Thx, what time period for cold or frozen indicies? Maybe you need all data in hot/warm until deletion and no further stages? How many replicas in each stage do you need? Repicas are essential for HA but also very handy if you want to increase search performance.

Comment: I need all data in hot/warm until deletion.

Comment: Got it. Replica factor in hot =1, warm = 1 or sth. different?

Comment: Would you recommend please how many replicat ?

Comment: It depends on the search load and HA requirements. Let us assume 1 for beginning, it can be increased at any time later by adding more nodes related to the wanted replica factor. I'm utc+1, will calculate and answer after the night. CU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220612/discussion-between-a-kram-and-ibexit).